# Change URL of previous posts and next posts link in Wordpress

Tags: posts, wp-query, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'd like to change the URL of the `<?php previous_posts_link ?>` and `<?php next_posts_link ?>` that are being outputted by *Wordpress*.

**Problem:**

> When I am on my single page, I am getting this kind of an url:
>
> http://example.com/post-title/2/

**What I like to achieve:**

> When I am on my single page, I would like to get:
>
> http://example.com/2/

**So, the URL without the post title!**

I don't know if this is even possible, but I'd like to understand if this is doable or not.

Could someone help me out here, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't make a lot of sense. http://example.com/2/ would be the second page of your blog. Why would that be the "next" link from a post?

Comment: Well, because I am fetching posts in my sidebar, which interacts with page/2/, page/3/ and so on. So it does make sense for me and it actually works fine on my homepage, but not on the single pages...

Comment: Nobody who can help?